# Adding a value to terms in a Map

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to add specific values to a map in `Java`, where the key is quite complex, but the value is a simple Double.

Currently I'm using, where foos is an instance of `java.util.TreeMap<Foo, Double>`, and `amount` is a `Double`, code like:

```
for (java.util.Map.Entry<Foo, Double> entry : foos.entrySet()){     
    foos.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() + amount);    
}
```

but this looks quite dirty in that I have to reinsert the element, and I'm worried about invalidating the iterator.

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm using the latest version of Java.

Comment: foos can't be an instance of Entry, because Entry doesn't have an entrySet() method. I think your foos is actually an instance of TreeMap.

Comment: Well done for getting your tags right. So many first time users of this site don't.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you are right. foos is an instance of a treemap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you only want to modify the values, you can use [`Map#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
foos.replaceAll((k, v) -> v + amount);
```

`merge` is useful if you potentially have new keys to insert, but that's not your case since you are iterating over the same set of keys.

Comment: 1 line compared to others doing forloops

Comment: Yes I like this a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use the `Map#merge` that, since Java version 8, has been available:

```
for (java.util.Map.Entry<Foo, Double> entry : foos.entrySet()){ 
    foos.merge(entry.getKey(), amount, Double::sum);    
}
```

Note the use of the *method reference* symbol `::`, not to be confused with the *scope resolution* operator of C++.

Here I'm using the "canned" function `Double::sum` but you can have lots of fun building your own which makes this approach particularly powerful. For more details see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-

Comment: I've only recently started using it. (But coming from C++ I wish they had not used the `::` operator.)

Comment: Yeah haha, that did throw me a little bit, but it was quickly outweighed by the fact that it's really quite powerful!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [entry.setValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#setValue-V-). The documentation says:

> Replaces the value corresponding to this entry with the specified value (optional operation). (Writes through to the map.)

So:

```
for (java.util.Map.Entry<Foo, Double> entry : foos.entrySet()){     
    entry.setValue(entry.getValue() + amount));
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a nice way. And will work pre-Java 1.8. Have an upvote!